# Azure Search performance while uploading content

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Lately I'm facing some performance issues while querying over my Azure search service index. I'm trying to figure out what happens. I came across the following article:

[Azure Search performance and optimization considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-performance-optimization)

It says:

> Uploading of content to Azure Search will impact the overall performance and latency of the Azure Search service. If you expect to send data while users are performing searches, it is important to take this workload into account in your tests.

I want to clarify something. If, for example, I have two indexes on my search service account, let say: index-a, index-b.

If I upload content to index-a, it will impact the overall performance and latency of index-b?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the pricing tier of your search service account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both indexes are within the same service, then yes, one index will have its performance affected by the other one. How much it's affected will depend on the service tier and the amount of information you are indexing.